# EPPlus - How to copy only cells with data?

Tags: epplus

How can I read an excel file and select ONLY those CELLS that have data - not formatting, not spaces , just text or numbers.

Using EPPlus?

I know I can read the spreadsheet like this : How can I do a 'select' on only those cells and make a copy.

(But  But these values are wrong !!
   int rowCount = excelRange.Rows.Count;
            int colCount = excelRange.Columns.Count;)

```
Excel.Application excelApp = new Excel.Application();
    if (excelApp != null)
    {
        Excel.Workbook excelWorkbook = excelApp.Workbooks.Open(@"C:\test.xls", 0, true, 5, "", "", true, Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "\t", false, false, 0, true, 1, 0);
        Excel.Worksheet excelWorksheet = (Excel.Worksheet)excelWorkbook.Sheets[1];

        Excel.Range excelRange = excelWorksheet.UsedRange;
        int rowCount = excelRange.Rows.Count;
        int colCount = excelRange.Columns.Count;

        for (int i = 1; i <= rowCount; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 1; j <= colCount; j++)
            {
                Excel.Range range = (excelWorksheet.Cells[i, 1] as Excel.Range);
                string cellValue = range.Value.ToString();

                //do anything
            }
        }

        excelWorkbook.Close();
        excelApp.Quit();
```

Answer (score 3):

You could take advantage of the fact that the `Worksheet.Cells` collection only contains entries with cells that have "content", i.e. Value, styling, etc.  So if you have a sheet like this:

[image]

And did something like this:

```
using (var pck = new ExcelPackage(fileInfo))
{
    var workbook = pck.Workbook;
    var worksheet = workbook.Worksheets.First();

    var valueCells = worksheet
        .Cells
        .Where(c => c.Value != null) //This will filter out the Yellow empty cells
        .ToList();

    valueCells.ForEach(c => Console.WriteLine($"{c.Start.Row},{c.Start.Column} = {c.Value}"));
}
```

Would give you this in the output:

```
1,1 = Col1
1,2 = Col2
1,3 = Col3
2,1 = 0
2,3 = thcu5qox.0ni
3,2 = 10
4,1 = 2
4,2 = 20
5,1 = 3
5,2 = 30
5,3 = 4gnyrwlr.twk
6,1 = 4
6,2 = 40
7,2 = 50
7,3 = nswaeft2.y1h
8,1 = 6
9,2 = 70
10,2 = 80
10,3 = qmz4tkd3.qcw
11,1 = 9
11,2 = 90
11,3 = zjahlstc.azr
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Dimension property on the worksheet to find out what the used range is.

Then you can run a Linq query on that range with a condition checking if a cells value is not null.